# matlab parfor is very slow with operation on a large matrix

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am writing a matlab code, which does some operations on a large matrix. First I create three 3D array

```
dw2 = 0.001;
W2 = [0:dw2:1];
dp = 0.001;
P1 = [dp:dp:1];
dI = 0.001;
I = [1:-dI:0];
[II,p1,ww2] = ndgrid(I,P1,W2);
```

Then my code basically does the following

```
G = [0:0.1:10]
Y = zeros(length(G),1)
for i = 1:1:length(G)
    g = G(i);
    Y(i) = myfunction(II,p1,ww2,g)
end
```

This code roughly takes about 100s, with each iteration being nearly 10s.

However, after I start `parfor`

```
 ProcessPool with properties: 

            Connected: true
           NumWorkers: 48
              Cluster: local
        AttachedFiles: {}
    AutoAddClientPath: true
          IdleTimeout: 30 minutes (30 minutes remaining)
          SpmdEnabled: true
```

Then it is like running forever. The maximum number of workers is 48. I've also tried 2, 5, 10. All of these are slower than non-parallel computing. Is that because matlab copied `II,p1,ww2` 48 times and that causes the problem? Also `myfunction` involves a lot of vectorization. I have already optimized the `myfunction`. Will that lead to slow performance of `parfor`? Is there a way to utilize (some of) the 48 workers to speed up the code? Any comments are highly appreciated. I need to run millions of cases. So I really hope that I can utilize the 48 workers in some way.

Comment: While using `ndgrid` can make code more readable it can increase the memeory usage and the computation time. In several problems that I have seen, broadcast operations and some other efficient vectorization operators can operate on the original variables like `W2 , P1, I`  instead of the equivalent full grid of the replicated vectors.

Comment: @rahnema1  I see. Thanks! But in my case, I think I have to work on the cubic. Because, I am solving an optimization problem in 3D by brutal force, i.e., I have to enumerate all combinations of `(W2,P1,I)` and find the global optimal point.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have large data, and a lot of MATLAB workers. The large data must be copied to each of the workers, and the results have to be copied back. This takes time. Also, using that many processes it is possible that you run out of memory, which will make things terribly slow.

I would suggest that you set up your workers to be threads, not separate processes. In this way, they use shared memory and the data doesn’t need copying.
You can do this with `parpool('threads')`. Your code must conform to some limitations, not all code can be run this way, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-functions-on-threads.html).

The process-based parallelism, with multiple copies of MATLAB, each with their own data, and communicating to copy data back and forth, was originally designed to work on a compute cluster. The system was later adapted to work on a single machine with multiple cores. I don’t think it’s an ideal system to use on a single machine, it was just easy to implement.

For more information, see [this documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html).